# Browser Certificate Not working for google and some other website

Tags: youtube, ssl-certificate, hsts

I am unable to open Google, Youtube, some other website in my browser. Its showing a Certificate authentication error.

I changed it as a trusted website. Now it showing like:

```
 (Index of /[ICO]   Name    Last modified   Size    Description)
```

I have no idea what to do. I am unable to google.

Other websites like facebook, yahoo and Gmail load correctly in the browser.

This is the message in google-chrome:

```
Your connection is not private

Attackers might be trying to steal your information from 
www.google.co.in (for example, passwords, messages, or 
credit cards).     NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
```

The Message I am getting in chrome when I click advanced:

```
Hide   Copy Code
www.google.co.in normally uses encryption to protect your 
information. When Chrome tried to connect to www.google.co.in 
this time, the website sent back unusual and incorrect 
credentials. Either an attacker is trying to pretend 
to be www.google.co.in, or a Wi-Fi sign-in screen has 
interrupted the connection. Your information is still secure 
because Chrome stopped the connection before any data was 
exchanged.

You cannot visit www.google.co.in right now because the 
website uses HSTS. Network errors and attacks are 
usually temporary, so this page will probably work later.
```

Is this a problem with google servers, something in between or the client side browser?  Is there a workaround for this error?

Comment: are you on your home network?

Comment: How can i check that ...

Answer (score 2):

This is a Chrome issues.  Switch to a different browser and you will be fine.  Google has decided to make getting to sites without the "expected" SSL certificate almost impossible (you can go clear the cached cert info on a site-by-site basis, which is a real pain...but expect the problem to come back again and then you have to go clear the cached cert again).

If you are using web filtering or various real security products that decrypt / inspect / then re-encrypt traffic, Chrome dumps all over it.

I used to be a Chrome fan, but because of this issue I had to abandon Chrome.  I'm not going to turn off my real security products just so I can keep using Chrome!